# How can we use multiple csv files in one spec file using Taiko+Gauge

Tags: automated-tests, browser-automation, gauge, getgauge, taiko

I am getting error when I declare different csv files according to test data to different scenarios on specs level while using Taiko + Gauge.

Any one can help on this?

Reference:
[specs with multiple csv files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXHwN.png)

eg.
table:specs/case_sclm.csv

- Verify test method1

table:specs/case_creation_ts_record.csv

- Verify test method2,
  Here both the above methods having 2 different csv files passed as arguments with test data.

Error showing is : Multiple data table present, ignoring table

Advance thanks for any leads or help!

Reference :
https://github.com/getgauge/gauge/issues/1518#issue-513703584

Answer (score 0):

A spec file can have only one table in this form:

`table:some/table.csv`

because Gauge will use this table for [data driven execution](https://docs.gauge.org/execution.html?os=linux&language=csharp&ide=vscode)

In order to pass tables as arguments, you need to use [Table Parameters](https://docs.gauge.org/writing-specifications.html?os=linux&language=csharp&ide=vscode#table-parameters)

In your example try something like this

```
* Verify test method <table:specs/case_sclm.csv>
* Verify test method <table:specs/case_creation_ts_record.csv>
```

The same step implementation will receive a `Table` object with data from respective csv files.